# Include php script in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

Hello I have this script to include in smarty

```
http://codecanyon.net/item/viral-lock-php-like-google1-or-tweet-to-unlock/1632879
```

How to do it easily?

I have tried this:

```
{php}
// inclusion directe d'un script PHP depuis le template.
include('/viral-lock.class.php');
include('/example.php');
{/php}
```

Comment: And what's the error? Does it work in pure PHP? What's your problem?

Comment: Remind me never to go on your site then...

Comment: Try this:
{include_php file='/path/to/load_nav.php'}
But could be deprecated. Depends of your verison of smarty. Check here: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.php.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
{include file="file.php"}
```